# Screen Blanking/Reducing back light on RPI while running a Kivy App

Tags: python, kivy

I have a kivy app that has multiple screens and widgets. I am using a motion sensor to check if there is motion and if there isn't any motion detected for 1 minute then the rpi reduces the screen's backlight or blanks the screen. Im not sure where I should place the rpi code. does it go inside the App class ?

Pir Module that works really well.

```
import time 
from gpiozero import MotionSensor 
import board 
import adafruit_dht 
import subprocess 

def turn_on(): 
    CONTROL = "vcgencmd" 
    CONTROL_UNBLANK = [CONTROL, "display_power", "1"]     subprocess.call(CONTROL_UNBLANK) 
def turn_off(): 
    CONTROL = "vcgencmd" 
    CONTROL_BLANK = [CONTROL, "display_power", "0"]     subprocess.call(CONTROL_BLANK) 
  
pir = MotionSensor(4) 
dhtDevice = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D23) 

while True:     
    if pir.motion_detected: 
        turn_on() 
        print("Motion Detected!") 
            try: 
                #Print the values to the serial port
                temperature_c = dhtDevice.temperature
                temperature_f = temperature_c * (9 / 5) + 32
                humidity = dhtDevice.humidity
                print("Temp: {:.1f} F / {:.1f} C  Humidity: {}% ".format(temperature_f, temperature_c, humidity)) 
            except RuntimeError as error: 
                # Errors happen fairly often, keep going 
                    print(error.args[0])             
                    time.sleep(2.0)             
                    continue 
            except Exception as error: 
                dhtDevice.exit()             
                raise error 
 
            time.sleep(60.0) 
            print("sleeping for 1 minute") 
    else: 
        turn_off() 
        print("No Motion Detected!")
```

Answer (score 1):

So I think I found a proper solution. The idea would be to use threading on the rpi. Its pretty simple to be honest. Here is the link to some code that has a gui but also uses a pir sensor to sense motion and adjust back lighting on the screen.
https://github.com/norrisredhi/kivy/blob/norrisredhi-patch-1/Kivyapp_with_threading_RPI.py